# Angle of Elevation and slope

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Standing on top of a gentle 5degree slope I see the top of a tall building at an angle of elevation of 35degree 15’.  I am 160 cm tall and it is 12 m from where I am standing to the foot of the building. 
Calculate how tall the building is?

Comment: Is 12m along the slope, or horizontal?

Answer (score 1):

Use trigonometry after drawing lines parallel to the ground from the foot and head of the person.

$Building Height=12\sin5^{\circ}+1.6+12\cos5^{\circ}\tan35^{\circ}15'$

Your answer is about 6.79686689258 meters.